# DatabaseIOException When Executing Query "Delete"

Tags: sqlite, blackberry, java-me

Can anybody help telling me what is wrong with my code? I am trying to connect to SQLite database, and executing some queries. when trying to create and open the database, create and insert the table, no exception returned. but when I try to execute delete statement,

> DatabaseIOException: File system error (12)

always returned. I don't know the cause of the exception exactly. would you tell me what usually cause this kind of exception? I don't even know when I need to close the database and when I don't need to. [this solution](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/DatabaseIOException-File-system-error-12-when-using-database/td-p/1684441) also makes me confused.

here is my code:

```java
public class DatabaseManager {

    Logger log = new Logger();
    Database db;

    public DatabaseManager() {
        createDatabase();
    }

    private void createDatabase() {

        // Determine if an SDCard is present 
        boolean sdCardPresent = false;
        String root = null;
        Enumeration enum = FileSystemRegistry.listRoots();
        while (enum.hasMoreElements()) {
            root = (String) enum.nextElement();
            if(root.equalsIgnoreCase("sdcard/")) {
                sdCardPresent = true;
            }     
        }
        if(!sdCardPresent) {
            alert("This application requires an SD card to be present. Exiting application...");
        }          
        else {    
            try {
                URI uri = URI.create("/SDCard/databases/MyAdvanceUI/myadvanceui.db");
                db = DatabaseFactory.openOrCreate(uri);
                db.close();
                //alert("Database OK!");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                //alert("Exception in createDatabase(): " + e);
            }
        }
   }

private void alert(final String message) {
    UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Dialog.inform(message);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
}

private void createTableTask() {
    try {
        URI uri = URI.create("/SDCard/databases/MyAdvanceUI/myadvanceui.db");
        db = DatabaseFactory.open(uri);
        Statement st = db.createStatement("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t_task (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + "client TEXT, task TEXT)");
        st.prepare();
        st.execute();
        st.close();
        db.close();
        //alert("Table Task created!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        //alert("Exception in createTableTask(): " + e);
    }
}

private void insertTableTask() {

    String[] clients = { "Budi Setiawan", "Dian Kusuma", "Joko Ahmad", "Titi Haryanto", "Wahyu" };
    String[] tasks = { 
        "Penawaran terhadap instalasi server",
        "Follow up untuk keperluan produk terbaru",
        "Pendekatan untuk membina relasi", 
        "Penawaran jasa maintenance",
        "Penawaran terhadap instalasi database" 
    };

    try {
        URI uri = URI.create("/SDCard/databases/MyAdvanceUI/myadvanceui.db");
        db = DatabaseFactory.open(uri);

        for(int i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {
            Statement st = db.createStatement("INSERT INTO t_task (client, task) VALUES (?, ?)");
            st.prepare();
            st.bind(1, clients[i]);
            st.bind(2, tasks[i]);
            st.execute();
            st.close();

        }
        db.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        //alert("Exception in insertTableTask(): " + e);
    }

}

public void loadInitialData() {
    createTableTask();
    insertTableTask();
}

public Cursor getTasks() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Cursor results = null;
    try {
        URI uri = URI.create("/SDCard/databases/MyAdvanceUI/myadvanceui.db");
        db = DatabaseFactory.open(uri);
        Statement st = db.createStatement("SELECT client, task FROM t_task");
        st.prepare();
        results = st.getCursor();

        return results;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        //alert("Exception: " + e);
    }

    return results;
}

public void delete(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {
        URI uri = URI.create("/SDCard/databases/MyAdvanceUI/myadvanceui.db");
        db = DatabaseFactory.open(uri);
        Statement st = db.createStatement("DELETE FROM t_task WHERE client=?");
        st.prepare();
        st.bind(1, string);
        st.execute();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        alert("Exception: " + e);
    }
    }

}
```

thank you for your help.

Comment: The `close` methods on objects representing database connections should always be inside `finally` blocks.

Comment: Use db.commitTransaction();
db.close();
It May work.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see that you close the statement and close the database after `select` and `delete` actions. Most probably you can't open database because it wasn't closed correctly.

**Big warning** SD card isn't available when user mounted devices to PC as external drive. Some devices are going without SD card preinstalled. DB operations are really slow on 5 OS devices. Your `alert` method code wan't close db what could be issue to open it after on the next application start.

**Warning** As @pankar mentioned in comment you should add `finally {}` where you will close resources for sure. In your current implementation if you get exception in execution you will never close database.

**Big improvements** You don't need to create and prepare statement every loop. Just do it before `for`. Do bind and execute every loop. And close statement after `for`.

**Improvements** You could keep one opened db during application run cycle. It will save you some line of code and time for opening closing.

**Notation** It's bad practice to have parameter named like 'string'. I would rename it to something more meaningful.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answers and advices. I appreciate it so much. now I just keep the database connected when the application is running and close the connection it when the application closed.

Comment: And you don't have exceptions anymore?

Comment: yes, now it doesn't show any exceptions anymore. I just call method openDatabase() (that I created) in constructor of main class (that extends UiApplication) and closeDatabase() (I created it as well) in overridden method requestClose().